# how to query delayed_job handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm playing with delayed_job and I need to delete all the job with a specified handler value, I tried in this way

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  def clean_jobs
    Delayed::Job.all.each do |job|
      job.delete if job.payload_object.auction_id == id
    end
  end
end
```

and it works but I have to go through the entire queue...not cool. How can i work around this?
Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are using payload_object, which is a YAML text.

May be this code do the same thing.

```
Delayed::Job.where("handler LIKE '%auction_id: #{id}%'").delete_all
```

And for double check:

```
Delayed::Job.where("handler LIKE '%auction_id: #{id}%'").each do |job|
  job.delete if job.payload_object.auction_id == id
end
```

Comment: You can use the space before the attribute and new line character afterwards to avoid having to check each payload_object - e.g. Delayed::Job.where("handler LIKE '% user_id: #{self.id}%\n'")